What is the difference between first step analysis and n-step matrix when solving for probability of reaching absorbing state?
Given this transition matrix for a time-homogeneous Markov Decision Process given the state space is $\{1, 2,..., 7\}$.
$$
\begin{Vmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{Vmatrix}
$$
where the goal is to find $\Pr\{X_T=3|X_0=4\}$ where $T=$min$\{n\geq0; X_n=3\}$, one can perform a first-step analysis and attain the value $\Pr\{X_T=3|X_0=4\}=\frac{5}{12}$.
What I am confused about is I believe that I should be able to get the same result via a 3-step matrix. I specifically mention 3 steps because that is what it takes to get the first nonzero value of getting from state 4 to state 3 (which would be $P^{(3)}_{43}=\frac{4}{27}$), which I believe should satisfy the definition of $T$ mentioned above, but the probabilities are clearly not the same which brings me to the question I asked above. Can anyone please explain?

(It is possible that $X$ is absorbed in state $7$ before reaching $3$. How is $T$ defined in that event? I'm guessing that you could use $T:=\min\{n\ge 0: X_n =3$ or $7\}$. Then $T$ is finite and either $X_T=3$ or $X_T=7$. You seek the probability of the first event, given that the chain started in state $4$.)
$P^{(3)}_{43}$ only accounts for the cases in which the chain gets to 3 in the fewest possible number of steps (i.e. 3); namely $4\to 1\to 2\to 3$ or $4\to 5\to 2\to 3$ or $4\to 5\to 6\to 3$. But it doesn't count the longer ways, for example $4\to 5\to 6\to 5\to 2\to 3$.

What I'm getting from your response is that when solving for $X_T$ via first-step analysis, $T$ does not just account for one of the absorbing states that $X$ could reach, but for all of them. Is that what you mean in the first sentence?

But even if $T$ is defined for reaching all the other absorbing states, wouldn't $\Pr{X_T=3|X_0=4}$ still give me the fewest possible number of steps given the definition of $T$? I'm not sure how the given definition of $T$ incorporated with the probability of reaching one of the absorbing states would also account for longer ways.
